# Fixed nav bar on top of .js page piling script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put a fixed nav bar on top of my web page, but I'm stuck.

I'm using a page piling javascript effect which is probably why it doesn't work as intended. This is the piling.js effect [demo](https://codepen.io/KraljD/pen/XjbYvA)

I tried adding the usual navigation tag on top of my code, but it pushes sections down and won't stay visible after scrolling to second section.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: in css use z-index to layer your navigation on the top of pagepiling div.

Comment: I tried that too, but no cigar. I added "z-indexer: 100;" to nav tag in css and it did nothing.

Comment: Add that css and navigation to the codepen demo

Comment: I noticed the position is misspelled in your css causing the issue :)

Comment: Oh, my bad :) Unfortunately, the issue remains. I updated codepen demo.

Comment: It's `z-index`, not `z-indexer`. Try it and it will show up.

Comment: Oh god, finally :) Thanks guys, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Adding z-index: 100; to nav (css) fixed it.

```
nav {
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 100;
}
```

[Fixed demo](https://codepen.io/KraljD/pen/XjbYvA)